# How to get network drive root location?

Tags: powershell

I need to get the root location of a network mapped drive. `Using Get-Location` looks promising.

```
PS W:\> (Get-Location).Drive

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
----           ---------     --------- --------      ---- 
W                 384.97        546.54 FileSystem    \\RT-AC66U\files
```

However, when I reference the `Root` member, it gives back the `Name` value.

```
PS W:\> (Get-Location).Drive.Root
W:\
```

How can I get the `Root` value?

Comment: `(Get-Location).Drive | Format-List *` and see that the name you want is 
`.Drive.DisplayRoot`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler; Many thanks.

Comment: You can see in $PSHOME/PowerShellCore.format.ps1xml where Microsoft, in their infinite wisdom, decided to label the `DisplayRoot` member as `Root`.

Answer (score 1):

A better way of viewing this information, in my opinion, is to run the following in a normal powershell console.. if ran in an elevated console it will return nothing.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk | select Name, ProviderName
```

That will show all of your mapped drives, including their letters and network locations.

Comment: With PowerShell evolving on OSX and Linux a cmdlet restricted to windows doesn't sound a **better** way to me. Get-Location or Get-PSDrive are IMO more universal.